# ArcGIS Field Calculator String to New String Does Not Remove Colon Formatting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I imported a CSV from NWS to a file geodatabase and would like to calculate a new field (Time1).

I used the following code. It succeeds with no errors. However, I want to remove the colons. I am not sure why they carry over to the new field? Both time and Time1 are string fields.

`Left( [time_],2  ) + Mid( [time_], 3,4 ) + " CST"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the replace function on the Time1 field in field calculator. Selected Python not VB.

```
!Time1!.replace(":","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
!time_!.split(":")[0]+" "+!time_!.split(":")[1]+" CST"
```